# Are there consumer ALUs in the GHz range?

Tags: integrated-circuit, alu

When browsing consumer ICs, I struggle to see parts that function faster than a few hundred MHz, let alone in the GHz range. (Mostly the chips I want are ALUs or something similar.)

Obviously computer ALUs function well into the GHz range, so If I wanted an ALU with comparable performance, is there a way to get one? Would I have to commission a company for a wafer?

Comment: What do you mean by "consumer ICs"?

Comment: How do you plan to interface such an ALU to the remainder of your circuit? At GHz frequencies, you're starting to require specialized transceiver and I/O design, which suggests that the cost is not worth it, as compared to simply integrating an entire CPU and using slower interfaces at the edge.

Comment: I'm surprised you can find standalone ALUs above 100 MHz. If you want a system (other than a CPU) that includes ALUs, you'd generally roll your own on an FPGA. It won't be in the GHz range (maybe up to 0.5GHz) but you can get high performance from a large number of  blocks (ALUs etc) working in parallel.

Answer (score 5):

It simply can't be done at that speed as a standalone chip. The ALUs in an Intel or ARM CPU chip only have to drive a limited amount of nearby circuitry on the same chip, which is why they can run so fast. There's no practical way to get the drivers required to send those signals off-chip to go that fast.

Even general-purpose CPUs only ran at tens of MHz initially. It was only the development of on-chip caches, which decoupled the CPU speed from the external bus speed, that allowed CPU clock speeds to break the 50 MHz barrier.

Comment: The first general-purpose CPUs I used ran at 1 MHz or less :). I think the Z-80 from Zilog was the first to hit 4 MHz, though I may be wrong, it was a long time ago...

Comment: @JohnD So slow ahhhhhhh